# Glitch in the highlight of the name in the chat

Tags: bug, status-completed, chat, display-names

My name is not properly highlighted in the chat when someone response to me. The highlight stops after HoLyVieR.

[image]

Comment: I vote user error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's by design -- the part that wasn't working correctly was the tab completer. This is fixed now, so you can chose if you want [status-bydesign] or [status-completed].

On a side note, viewing your user profile on chat.meta currently throws a SqlException:

> Incorrect syntax near 'DO'.

-- I'm not very proficient in SQL, so can you explain this to me please?

Comment: Since `UNION` is a valid SQL operator, it probably jammed trying to interpret the word `DO`, so spit out the thing it choked on

Comment: @YiJiang yeah, I guess it was a bad joke...

Comment: I vote for [status-completed], [status-bydesign] means nothing was fixed.

Comment: @hol your wish is my command