# Glitch in the highlight of names in chat - not fixed

Tags: bug, status-completed, chat

[This bug](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64101/glitch-in-the-highlight-of-the-name-in-the-chat) was marked as fixed, but it doesn't look like it:

[image]

Notice how it only partially highlights my display name.

Comment: Yay parsing bugs!

Comment: These two issues have nothing to do with each other.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For some reason the highlighting code considered an underscore to not be a legal user name character. So it actually didn't have anything to do with your face – although that's bound to cause some issues, since for JavaScript, those thingys aren't letters. Either way, the highlighting is fixed in the next build.